# find all pages on a site that use a particular selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to modify properties of a selector(let's say #myList) that is used on few pages of website I'm working on. I want to make sure my changes won't ruin the design. Is there a tool that will generate a list of all pages on a website that uses a particular selector? (I don't know on which pages selector is used. The site has too many pages so doing it manually won't work.)

Comment: Are you working on Windows or Linux/Mac? If the latter, you can use grep to search for the string representing your selector inside all files.

Comment: No. I'm working on PC using DreamWeaver and use FileZilla to ftp files

Comment: Can you upload a php script? If you can, maybe we can generate a script that'll list all the pages for you. I don't know of a tool that can crawl the site and find what you want, but there must be one out there.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a command line tool called Element Finder which lets you enter in a CSS selector, like "#myList", and then searches through the directory and finds all of the HTML files with elements matching that selector.

You will need to install Element Finder, cd into the directory you want to search, and then run:

```
elfinder -s "#myList"
```

Or:

```
elfinder -s "#foo > .bar p > td .baz"
```

For more info please see http://keegan.st/2012/06/03/find-in-files-with-css-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/your/project -name '*.html' -exec grep -l 'id="myList"' {} \;
```

Of course, change the path and/or extension to suit your needs.

**Edit:** I should also note that this method will only work for non-nested/advanced selectors.  If you're trying to find elements matching `#foo > .bar p > td .baz` or something ridiculous, then the answer is probably no.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is there a PC or DreamWeaver solution?

Comment: I don't use DreamWeaver, but I imagine it has project support and the ability to search all files in a project.  If so, just use that to search for the id, class, etc.